# Compile Error Array Expected - Ubound - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am encountering a error  **Compile Error  Array Expected**.  Am I using Ubound incorrectly? Should I declare `myarray("Measurement", "", "Nominal", "Low", "High", "", "")` With a `Dim` statement at the opening? If so then how to do I hande the rest of the statement?

```
   Private Sub Format_Parse_Replace()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim NomValue As String
    Dim myarray As String


    Dim rLastCell As Range
                Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    'MsgBox ("The last used column is: " & rLastCell.Column)
        Rows("4:6").EntireRow.Insert

        myarray = Array("Measurement", "", "Nominal", "Low", "High", "", "")
            Range("A2:A" & UBound(myarray) + 1) = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray)

    For i = rLastCell.Column To 2 Step -1
            'If Cells(1, i) = "Logbook" Then
                'Columns(i).Delete
            'End If
            'Set Col = ColLett(rLastCell.Column)
           NomValue = ws.Cells(3, i).Value
           Columns(i).Cells(4).NumberFormat = "@"
           Columns(i).Cells(5).NumberFormat = "@"
           Columns(i).Cells(6).NumberFormat = "@"
           Columns(i).Cells(4) = SplitString(NomValue, ",", 4)
           Columns(i).Cells(5) = SplitString(NomValue, ",", 5)
           Columns(i).Cells(6) = SplitString(NomValue, ",", 6)

    Next i
    Rows(3).Delete

    End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel Help:  Array Function: Returns a Variant containing an array.

```
Dim myarray As String
```

Change to

```
Dim myarray As Variant
```